# Finding an element in jquery with some kind of a placeholder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html

I have a nested table structure, a part of which is rendered by a ajax call that returns HTML from the server. The markup looks like this:

```
.. some html here
        <tr>
          <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <%-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 1 --%>
              <%-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 2 --%>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
.. more html
```

The ajax call returns the following html

```
<tr>
<td class="wpss_checkboxtd"><img width="16" height="16" src="../../images/someimg.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="wpss_checkboxtd"><img width="16" height="16" src="../../images/someimg.png"></td>
</tr>
```

In jquery, I need to insert this html for which i need an element to traverse to so that I can call the html() of that element. Unfortunately, if I use a div, for example:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<div id="divAjax1">
              <%-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 1 --%>
</div>
<div id="divAjax2">
              <%-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 2 --%>
</div>
</table>
```

the classes are setup such that the div or a span causes other issues.

All I need is a way to identify where to insert this HTML from JQuery. Any ideas how I'd do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/tbody) sections, and place the IDs on those.

That way you'll have valid HTML markup:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<thead>
              <!-- header section -->
</thead>
<tbody id="divAjax1">
              <!-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 1 -->
</tbody>
<tbody id="divAjax2">
              <!-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 2 -->
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Great solution. I guess I can get away with using a tbody as my markup is within a table. What if it was in a different element (say <div>)

Comment: @DotnetDude: If you mean the `<div>` as a direct child of the `<table>` element, then no, it probably won't work. Web browsers will likely modify your HTML structure to make it valid, and the result may be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("td > table").html(<HTML from your AJAX call>)` to inser the HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxCall1() {
            debugger;
            var html = '<tr><td class="wpss_checkboxtd">ajaxcall 1 <img width="16" height="16" src="../../images/someimg1.png"></td></tr>'

            $(html).appendTo("#foo");
        }
        function ajaxCall2() {
            var html = '<tr><td class="wpss_checkboxtd">ajaxcall 2 <img width="16" height="16" src="../../images/someimg2.png"></td></tr>'

            $(html).appendTo("#foo");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="ajaxCall1()" value="ajax call 1" />
<input type="button" onclick="ajaxCall2()" value="ajax call 2" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="foo">
                    <%-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 1 --%>
                    <%-- Content will be displayed from ajax call 2 --%>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```